# Is this Fourier Transform for the Dirac Delta correct?

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta, quantum-mechanics

I'm reading "Schaum's Outlines: Quantum Mechanics" and in chapter 2 they define the Fourier transform of the Dirac Delta as:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-y)e^{-ikx}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-ikx} $$

But shouldn't it be $(1/\sqrt{2\pi})e^{-iky}$, using the fundamental property of the $\delta$-function?

Comment: Yep.  With the $y$.

Comment: Yes, the integral, since itis a definite integral and has a $dx$ in it, is not a function of $x.$ $x$ doesn't mean anything outside the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Take a look at the third property in this [link](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/diracdeltafunction.aspx#:%7E:text=There%20are%20three%20main%20properties,t%3D1%2C%CE%B5%3E0). Then take the limit as $\epsilon\rightarrow\infty$.